# How to load data from mysql db on start up .Net Core Web API service application?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, data-access-layer, rest

I am new to .Net Core and MySql.

I am trying to develop an service application which would provides multiple types of data to other applications via REST api call using .Net Core and MySql.

I am not able to figure out how to load all the data at start of the application, so that when api calls are triggered, the response can be generated with the data already loaded in the application instead of fetching it from database for each request.

Please suggest an efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, depending on your data, this might be a bad idea to load everything. But if you really want that (it might take the app long to start if you do it), you can do this as on any other location in the configure services part of your startup for example.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it by using a class that handles the connection to the database and then you have methods for each way you want to access data. Then on the first fetch you collect the data you need from the database and then cache it for the next call. That way you don't need to keep everything in memory if you don't need it.

But if you really need full speed preloading (if possible) is the way to go. Then it depends much of how your data i structured. I would probably load all data into classes so they are already in the correct format and then use a dictionary with the appropriate keys to get the data out of the dictionary. The problem will be if it will be possible to get data in many different ways. If you have database with persons you could create a Person class with all the information about the person and then use the email as the unique identifier so when your other application want all info of a Person by using email a dictionary will be superfast. But if you also want to get all persons in a city or with a specific first name the dictionary will be slow since you will have to loop through all items to look for the city or name.

I would put in my time on how all the searches will be and if you have an id as a unique identifier of a person you could use that in the dictionary and then use a seperate dictionary for each search. So one dictionary where the key is the email and the value points to the unique id in the dictionary with all users. And then another dictionary for cities where the dictionary contains a list of all ids of persons in that city and so forth. In this way you are creating a kind of index like the database uses to fetch data fast.

But it really depends on your data. Is it very complex. Are there a lot of items in the database? Are there a lot of tables which will have there own searches? Can you search for the items in many ways? Will it be allowed to search using wildcards?

The problem is that you are trying to create a temporary in-memory database using the real database as a starting point. And it's not possible to ask someone which is the most efficient way to create a database. To be able to answer that you will need more info.

If you need even more speed you could also pre-serialize all responses and keep them as strings so you can send json (or which format you now will use) straight away. The problem is the more speed you need the more "ugly" the code will get and you will pay for it in memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. What you have elaborated above is what the vague idea I had in my mind.There are around 15 different types entities stored in tables for each type. Can hav a DataServiceControl class which will use the connectionString from appsetting.json and load the data into dictionaries. Now I need to figure out how to structure all it and design interfaces/abstract class that could be then implemented by DataServiceClass for each entity. Yes, there will be lot of memory consumption by the service application, but the idea here is fast retrieval of data.